# How do I choose an existing SciTE lexer for a custom file extension?

Tags: scite

Whenever I open a *.log file with SciTE, I then click to change the language to "errorlist".  I have searched to try to find how to configure SciTE to automatically associate this style with the extension, but have had no success.  There's a lot of information about how to write your own lexer, but not much on how to use an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to associate *.lib files to cpp lexer:

I added the lines

```
file.patterns.cplusplus=$(file.patterns.cplusplus);*.lib
lexer.$(file.patterns.cplusplus)=cpp
```

to the User properties file.

`cpp` in the second line refers to the file "cpp.properties". (And `file.patterns.cplusplus` is one of the patterns defined in that file.)

I dont know which file corresponds to the Errorlist language, you can look for it in the Menu:

```
Options -> Edit Properties
```